# iOS, config files and sandboxing

Tags: ios, config, sandbox

My understanding is that because of sandboxing, it isn't possible to view any text file (ie config file) associated with an iOS app using another app. Something quite simple with Android. Am I mistaken?

I am trying to implement a text config file with a Unity iOS app that gets loaded and parsed once when the application boots.
This config file would also be able to be edited and saved manually on that actual iOS device.

(addendum)
In Unity there is PersistentDataPath which resolves to `/var/mobile/Container/Data/Application/foo/Documents`

Is there an iOS supported file explorer app that will allow me view and edit files in this location (without jailbreaking)?

Comment: You mean a settings bundle? That's what a settings bundle is for. Unless you mean something else?

Comment: Are you asking if the *user* can simply open a text file on iPhone / iPad with a text editor to make changes?

Comment: OP. Please see revised post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use can check iOS `App Groups`. It allows multiple apps access to shared containers and allow interprocess communication. There is no so much documentation about this, but maybe that's what you're looking for. At least you can share `NSUserDefaults` between the apps.
2. `NSUserDefaults` it's a most simple way to save any (not big) configurations for your  app. For manual editing: if your app on the device signed with developer certificate, you can connect through any iOS supported file explorer app and edit it. But after release, from App Store, your app installed in restricted/private path, so it's not possible, if only you don't have a jailbreak.
3. Initial configuration you can put into your app bundle, and at the first run just copy them to `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: I should mention this is NOT an Objective C app, but rather C#, Unity. In Unity there is PersistentDataPath which resolves to /var/mobile/Container/Data/Application/foo/Documents. Is there an  iOS supported file explorer app that will allow me view and edit files in this location? Thanks again!

Comment: You can try iFunbox or iExplorer. This explorers supports iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: There are utilities such as iExplorer - https://macroplant.com - that allow "file manager" type access. However...

Long answer: If your app *requires* users to buy (or get) other software to modify configuration files, the chances of Apple approving it are slim to none.

The appropriate thing to do is to provide a User Interface in your own app which allows the user to modify / update the settings.

Comment: this is not going to the App Store